# Can i get my double spending bitcoin back in my wallet

Tags: blockchain-wallet-app

I opened my wallet and saw that blockchain sent my bitcoin to a bitcoin address, and it is still unconfirmed after 2 days, can they still return my bitcoin?

Comment: Your transaction will eventually get confirmed, or dropped if it takes too long to get confirmed and you will be able to see your bitcoins in your wallet again. Check out the answer from this question: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it